16 RS485 sensor connectors
I am designing a PCB with 16 RS485 connectors. My idea is to create a "short" RS485 bus on PCB using PCB traces with 120 Ohm resistors on both ends. And then connect the 16 RS485 sensors to that bus by keeping an equal distance of 1 ... 1.2 cm between them. The individual cables going from PCB to the RS485 sensors need to be between 1m and 10m long and will carry (PWR, GND, A+ and B-).
The speed can be up to 115200 bps.
The background considerations for this approach is to get as close as possible to a bus topology as opposed to the star topology.
From an overall wiring perspective, imagine the following: A single PLC box with 16 RJ45 connectors for 16 RS485 sensors.

Are there any issues with my design considerations?

Is there a minimum required distance between RS485 devices on the same bus?

Is there a maximum length for the cable connecting an RS485 device with the RS485 bus?

Any other things I would need to consider?



The fundamentals of RS485 are all about length vs timing.  You need to think about what speed you are using to answer this question.  So: what is the bit rate?

the term is star, not start

The speed can be up to 115200 bps.

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/307664/about-driving-leds-over-long-distances/307690#307690  upto 100 kBd * 1 km product, so lots of margin but I hope you don't mean 16 Tx + 1 Rx = 17 terminators on same bus  120/17 ohms

I was planning to terminate the bus with 2 120 Ohm resistors on both ends (no 17 terminators). But in my case, the bus will be super short - somewhere 30 and 40cm.

RS485 was designed for daisy-chain not that

I understand, RS485 can be wired as daisy-chain and as bus. Daisy chain simply doesn't work for my setup.

I took the liberty of editing in the speed from asker's comment.

What protocol are you using for clock/data recovery?  Double terminating a 120 ohm differential line this short is essentially the same as one at half the resistance with a 1 ns T-line. The noise will be closer to threshold reducing margin for other interference. It is workable but slew rate limiting and also include ESD protection is important for reliability.

If using a UART use some fail-safe bias towards a stop bit.

One difficulty with RS-485 is that you will read, everywhere, that stub lengths should be "as short as possible", and designers will go to absurd lengths saving a millimetre here or there.  This is is nonsense: engineering is about measuring things and being reasonable.
Stub length calculation
The question is: how long is a short cable?
Texas Instruments' excellent Application Note 1057  Ten Ways to Bulletproof RS-485 Interfaces contains the key information (section 6) about how stub length limits should be calculated:

You need to know the length of the stub
You need to know the bit rate, or more precisely the rise time of the transmitter

A short cable is one where echoes arrive well within the rise time.
In brief, it says a stub should be less than a quarter of the rise time of the transmitter.  If you use a slew-rate limited transmitter it will reduce EMI and have a long rise time.  Typical 115 kbit/sec example part would be Texas Instruments SN65HVD1780, with a rise time minimum of 400 ns (typ is 1.4 μs); with signal propagation at 0.6 c, that's a length of 72 m.  A quarter of which is 18 metres. (400e-9 sec x 0.6 * 3e8 m/sec * 0.25 = 18 m)
Your 10 cm bus with 1 to 10 metre stubs thus sounds viable to me at this relatively slow bitrate, and with correctly chosen transmitters.
NB: Texas Instrument's RS-485 Design Guide gives slightly different values: a more-conservative tenth of the rise time, and less-conservative 0.78 c for propagation ... giving 9.36 m max stub against min rise time.  Same answer: likely to work fine.
A client of mine had a system where they looped the signal in and out of each device in order to get stubs of about 1 cm.  But it was only 250 kbit/sec.  We built a test setup with stubs about 0.5 m off a bus of about 30 m, and honestly the signals look like a textbook.  They saved a lot of money because this permitted halving the number of very expensive underwater connectors, while simultaneously improving overall reliability because the dominant cause of system failure was water ingress at the connectors.
I suggest you try it and measure everything carefully before committing though.
Alternative Cabling
If you're using RJ-45 connectors you have enough pins to loop the signal in and out of each device without any additional costs.  If you have choice of pinout, you could consider an arrangement like the following, which (with 16 x 10 m cables) would give you a pure 320 m bus with sub 1-cm stubs.
This would generally be considered the "correct" RS-485 solution (but you need to pay a little attention as 300 metres is not quite negligible at 115.2 kbit/sec.)

NB: 75176 driver shown just for "standard pinout", and just one possible Cat-5 assignment of data lines chosen to similar to DMX512, power lines like typical power-over-cat5 modelled on POE Mode B, DC on spares
Errors
You don't describe your upper protocols.  If it tolerates errors (perhaps the slaves spontaneously transmit and might collide), then error rates from less-than-optimal cabling will also get accommodated.  Estimating the error rate is extremely difficult, but measuring it is not.  Recommendation: Add error detection if you don't already have it.
Choice of speed
You don't say why you've chosen 115,200 bit/sec.
If you think you might need considerably faster in the future, you have to improve the cabling and shorten the stubs.  It's horrible to have your hardware hold you back, and saying "Sorry Client, we can't increase the speed because we took some value-choices on the bus topology" often goes down very badly.
On the other hand, if you can go slower, you will probably increase reliability by a lot.  I like to use 9600 bit/sec unless the application demands faster: at this speed, almost any kind of cabling will work perfectly.  (Also means I can leave all the debugging tools at the same speed, and you can put LEDs on the devices to see when they're transmitting)  If you're polling something slow-moving like temperature sensors, consider this.
Recommendation: review your speed choice carefully.
Minimum and Maximum Cable Lengths
Maximum cable length is determined by one of three things:

At the lowest speeds, the limiting factor is cable resistance and is roughly 1 km
At the highest speeds, the limiting factor is driver rise time, and is roughly 10 m.
In between, there's a tradeoff, a very conservative rule of thumb is 107 / bits/sec, in metres; ie, at 100 kbit/sec, length limit is 100 metres; others such as ABB give 108.

Both the TI documents have graphs and elaboration on this.  TI says the 107 "is far more conservative than today's cable performance", most sources say 115.2 kbit/sec will go 1200 m.
Minimum device separation is determined by various capacitances and under some conditions can be as large as 0.4 m, though is more usually much smaller.
As your minimum cable is 1 m you don't have to worry about this.
See TI Design Guide section 10 for a graph and formulas.
References

Texas Instruments Application Note 1057  Ten Ways to Bulletproof RS-485 Interfaces
Texas Instrument's RS-485 Design Guide
Texas Instruments RS-485 Industrial Workhorse Crash Course and Design Guide
Maxim Application Note 3884 how far and how fast can you go with RS-485
Max Linear Application Note 292 RS-485 Cable Lengths
against Data Signaling Rate
ABB RS-485 Design and install best practices
Also, if you haven't read it, Bob Perrin's Circuit Cellar article The Art and Science of RS-485 is invaluable.


Well done Jonathon

Thank you for your explanations. They do make sense to me. The controllers we are using of this type SN65HVD75. One thing concerns me that the response from Justme is somehow the opposite from what you described - regarding the bus length. But your explanations seem to be backed by formulas.

@user14665305  Do not use the 75 but rather the SN65HVD72 for ringing resonance control or SN65HVD1780   !!!  This is the most critical change

@user14665305 Justme says "For really short cables, slow bit rate, and RS-485 PHYs with slow slew rate, it may work, but it's not the intended topology."  It's not opposite: in essence I was trying to quantify short and slow.  NB I've added a few sentences about errors in my answer.

Regarding if there are any issues, yes.
You are effectively designing a star bus, where all sensor have one cable leading to a one common point.
Normally an RS-485 bus is e.g. a 10 meter linear bus with e.g. 1 meter stubs on it for each sensor. You are doing exactly opposite, having a 1 meter linear bus with e.g. 10 meter stubs on it for sensors.
So all connections are stubs to the actual bus that is basically infinitecimally short.
So you will have all problems of a star bus.
You cannot terminate the sensor end of the cable because the hub already terminates the bus twice. Therefore all the signals reflect back from the open end of the cable back to hub.
Also the hub is basically a single star point with double termination, so it also does not match the cable impedance, which again causes reflections back to sensor cable.
Also the main bus, being effectively a star point with many stubs, needs to drive each stub, but each stub loads the  bus with the characteristic impedance of the cable.
The bus is difficult to manage as it depends on how long each cable to sensor is, and how many sensors there are connected.
For really short cables, slow bit rate, and RS-485 PHYs with slow slew rate, it may work, but it's not the intended topology.
Which is why all application notes explicitly state that a star bus is not a suggested topology.
You might be able to rework the idea to have a physical star topology with a physical linear RS-485 bus where the bus simply loops through each device and back to hub.
Or have the hub with 16 separate RS-485 ports so you can do point-to-point wiring with a bus to each sensor.

This is what Circuit Cellar recommended in 1999 with what you have in the Star network.

This suggests your plan could be changed.

eliminate 1 of 2 bus terminators

Your backbone is just a point like the green square I added in the star, it can be workable with 10 m stubs if you limit the rise time. There is no need to double-terminate at one point.




TI reports you might be better off with no terminators using their bridge driver (115kBd slew rate limited) But not the same topology.  

make your differential Zo load match your cable or up to 25% higher. Lower Rterm reduces your jitter margin from undershoot.  Reason: The driver is like a 4V TTL driver except as a >150mA voltage source, not a current source. e.g. approx 23 ohm diff.(?) ) So no load will be 8Vpp at source but ringing is a percentage of peak-based return loss so over-attenuating with 2 Rterms degrades the margin. Ringing is from 10 m stubs with the junction capacitance of disabled sensor drivers & circuit.

Reducing your slew rate is the best way to eliminate the spectrum that resonates in your mismatched T-line!

this can be done with ferrite beads and RC filters or drivers with reduced slew rates like the MAX3483 or equiv... SN65HVD72 https://www.analog.com/media/cn/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1079.pdf


if you want to eliminate all but 1 connector on your PCB, use the daisy-chain cables.  Wire is cheap but it means you need a custom harness to go in and back out near the Rx but out to the next Tx and repeat... Signal quality is Priceless!  You use twice as much cable or more with a terminator on both ends but you'll be able to disconnect sensors live without having to access the Rx board and reduce your board size + cost and get better signal quality.

for testing with a sig gen use 1/3 of the bit rate and simulate 011 or 100.
This is an ideal test for testing ISI and bit edge shift from unequal group delays, which I used in all my data-comm designs in addition to PSRG data.
There are still unanswered concerns about power sequencing/ multiplexing sensor drivers that must be disabled, your data/clock protocol and the flexibility of your cable scheme.


Conclusion:
Although I answered late to the party, you should not have too much trouble getting reliable data from your sensors if you can manage to match impedance at your Rx and reduce your Tx slew rate for 250 kBd.  But if you want extra insurance from unknown ESD events, stray lightning noise etc, the daisy-chain is a better solution for signal integrity.

Could you explain how this is calculated: "60 ps = 10 m cable (1/2 wave) or 120 ps cycle ~ 8 MHz approx." ?  8 MHz surely has a cycle of 125 nano seconds?

argh brainfart sorry

:-) phew, thought it me was me!  I confess I still don't see where 120 ps cycle comes from.

I'm still confused by this. 1/(vcl) has dimensions L²/T and thus here would be 500e-12 m²/s, which I'm struggling to interpret.  Don't we want a straightforward distance / speed? With dimension T, ie 10 m / 2e8 m/s = 50e-9 = 50 ns; round-trip = 100 ns.

yes my bad. I excelled at the impossible and now can't do the mundane.  I used to correct my professors errors all the time, so I guess this is karma
